# Parse Last.Fm XML from API in Java

Tags: java, xml

URL: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gethypedtracks&api_key=1732077d6772048ccc671c754061cb18&limit=10

From the above url I need to somehow remove the Artist name and the track name from the XML file produced from each Song given but I have no Idea how to work with an XML file structured in this way ??

Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated !

Thanks, 
    Ross

Comment: Do you want to remove them from the file, or extract them? What output are you expecting? There's nothing wrong with the xml you get from that URL, it just formats oddly, but you can use something like `xmlstarlet fo -s 2 file.xml` to reformat it so you can understand its layout better.

Comment: I want to extract the song and artist names from the XML file but I am unsure of hot to deal with this oddly formatted file ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fully working class that loads the URL you have indicated and parses the Track and artist names.

Basically it reads the xml into a Document, and runs 2 xpath queries in loops to get the data you want.

The document itself is simple xml, if you reformat it, it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lfm status="ok">
  <tracks page="1" perPage="10" totalPages="50" total="500">
    <track>
      <name>Hysterical</name>
      <duration>231</duration>
      <percentagechange>3626</percentagechange>
      <mbid/>
      <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Clap+Your+Hands+Say+Yeah/_/Hysterical</url>
      <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
      <artist>
        <name>Clap Your Hands Say Yeah</name>
        ...
```

All I did to clean it up was run it through a re-formatter like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) as I mentioned in my comment. Note: you don't have to reformat it for java to read it if it's well formed. Human readable is all a re-format does for you.

The first xpath query gets the track name using a path `lfm/tracks/track/name`. You can use something like [this xpath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/test) to try out your xpath queries (you can paste your xml in and it will reformat it too). If you don't understand xpath, there are many sources on the net.

The second xpath works relative to the current track name node, and looks for a `following-sibling` node of type `artist` with a `name` sub-node, and then displays the text of the node.

Here's the code

```
package net.fish;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ParseXML {

    private static final DocumentBuilderFactory DOCUMENT_BUILDER_FACTORY = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    private static final XPathFactory XPATH_FACTORY = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ParseXML().parseXml("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gethypedtracks&api_key=1732077d6772048ccc671c754061cb18&limit=10");
    }

    private void parseXml(String urlPath) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        DocumentBuilder db = DOCUMENT_BUILDER_FACTORY.newDocumentBuilder();

        final Document document = db.parse(connection.getInputStream());
        XPath xPathEvaluator = XPATH_FACTORY.newXPath();
        XPathExpression nameExpr = xPathEvaluator.compile("lfm/tracks/track/name");
        NodeList trackNameNodes = (NodeList) nameExpr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < trackNameNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node trackNameNode = trackNameNodes.item(i);
            System.out.println(String.format("Track Name: %s" , trackNameNode.getTextContent()));
            XPathExpression artistNameExpr = xPathEvaluator.compile("following-sibling::artist/name");
            NodeList artistNameNodes = (NodeList) artistNameExpr.evaluate(trackNameNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int j=0; j < artistNameNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                System.out.println(String.format(" - Artist Name: %s", artistNameNodes.item(j).getTextContent()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !  This is exactly what I needed and well explained ! Thanks